# Django Overwrite Forms for django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to customise the standard forms that come with django all-auth

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS={
    'login'                     : 'CustomLoginForm',
    'signup'                    : 'CustomSignupForm',
    'reset_password'            : 'CustomResetPasswordForm',
    'change_password'           : 'CustomChangePasswordForm',
}
```

In the above, login, signup and reset_password all get modified to my custom forms, as desired, but change_password does not.

Does anyone know how to overload the change_password form?

Cheers,